# How to find out which Maven dependency bring another dependency (artifact) in Intellij

Tags: maven

Basically I need to update gson to latest version (2.8.9), but as it is not included in POM directly, how can I find out which dependency brings it?
In Intellij, in Maven "Dependencies tree" I'm able to manually open them one by one, but is there any automatic way how to do it?

Comment: is `mvn dependency:tree` good enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=com.google.code.gson:gson` to check for dependencies which bring `gson` into your project.
2. Use `<dependencyManagement>` [section of the POM](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management) to control the versions of artifacts used in transitive dependencies. Just add the following snippet:

   ```
   <dependencyManagement>
     <dependencies>
       <dependency>
         <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
         <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
         <version>2.8.9</version>
       </dependency>
     </dependencies>
   </dependencyManagement>
   ```

Comment: Thanks found the dependency which brings the older version. Probably I need to exclude it from there and add newer version separately.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding, you're opening dependencies in maven tab one by one. In terminal tab, run mvn dependency:tree and you'll be able to see entire tree with version details.